# How to copy file using adb to android directory accessible from PC

Tags: android, adb, android-external-storage

If you attach android device to PC you can browse files and dirs. It is possible to get this directory using `Environment.getExternalStorage()`. You can use it from your application and create accessible files and dirs. It works fine.

On my devices this path looks like `/storage/emulated/0` and if i try `adb push` to this directory i will get access denied error. Is it possible to copy files using `adb` to the same folder as Windows Explorer does?

```
D:\...\tools>adb push ACCOUNTS.DB /storage/emulated/0
failed to copy 'ACCOUNTS.DB' to '/storage/emulated/0': Permission denied
58969 KB/s (606505 bytes in 0.010s)
```

I'm implementing automated import/export and i want files to be accessible without `adb shell` in case anything will go wrong.

Currently using variable`$EXTERNAL_STORAGE` as workaround, it works for both `adb` and application.

Device: Asus Fonepad 7, Android 5.0, tried Genymotion Custom Tablet 6.0 - works.

Comment: `adb push ... /storage/emulated/0` works fine for me, testing on a Nexus 5X running Android 6.0.1.

Comment: it is the problem, i need it to work *reliably*, but it fails on my own device, works with emulator.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try to use `/sdcard/`. Although it is strongly discouraged to do this in *code*. It seems to be the only way with *adb* :

```
$ adb push somefile /storage/emulated/0/somefile
[100%] /storage/emulated/0/somefile
adb: error: failed to copy 'somefile' to '/storage/emulated/0/somefile': Read-only file system

$ adb push somefile /sdcard/somefile
[100%] /sdcard/somefile
```

By the way, on my device they don't have the same value : `Environment.getExternalStorage()` points to `/storage/emulated/0/` while `/sdcard` points to `/storage/emulated/legacy`.

Comment: File was copied successfully (and i can see it in the right place with ES Explorer), but it is not visible from PC. Tried reconnecting, waiting... perhaps i need somehow trigger indexing.

Comment: Well, it seems `MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE` broadcast can fix it.

Answer (score 2):

It's pretty easy, internal storage is unavailable on non-rooted devices. So as was mentioned in [bwt answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39508829/3874721) you just need to push your data to sdcard :

```
adb push somefile /sdcard/somefile
```

With retrieving files from your filesystem you'll also have few problems. But with the case of pulling a database from a debug application - you'll just need to change file permission via `chmod`.
Here you have a useful link   - [XDA guys about adb](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2266638)